# Do CPUs with AVX2 or newer instruction sets support any form of caching on register renaming?

Tags: caching, rename, cpu-registers, avx2, avx512

For example, there is a very simple pseudo code with many duplicated values taken:

```
Data:
   1 5 1 5 1 2 2 3 8 3 4 5 6 7 7 7

For all data elements:
    get particle id from data array
    idx = id/7
    index = (idx << 8) | id
    aabb = lookup[index]
    test collision of aabb with a ray
```

so that it will very probably re-compute same value of 1 for same division followed by same bitwise operation, with no loop carried dependency.

Can new CPUs (like Avx512 or AVX2) remember the pattern (same data + same code path) and directly rename an old input register and return the output quickly (like predicting branch but instead predicting register renamed for a temporary value)?

I'm currently developing a collision detection algorithm on an old CPU (bulldozer ver.1) and any online C++ compiler is not good enough for having predictable performance due to cpu being shared by all visitors.

Removing duplicates by using an unoredered map takes about 15-30 nanoseconds per insert or by using a vectorized plain array scan about 3-5 nanoseconds per insert. This is too slow to effectively filter unnecessary duplicates out. Even if a direct-mapped cache is used (that contains just a modulo operator and some assignments), it still fails (due to cache miss) even worse than using an unordered map in terms of performance.

I'm not expecting a cpu with only hundred(s) of physical registers to actually cache many things, but it could help a lot in computing duplicate values quickly, by just remembering the "same value + same code path" combo only from the last iteration of a loop. At least some physics simulations with collision checking could get a decent boost.

Processing a sorted is faster, but only for branching code? What about branchless code, with newest cpus?

Is there any way of harnessing the register renaming performance (zero latency?) as a simple caching of duplicated work?

Comment: No, that's not how register renaming works.  It's not a cache, and searching all other physical registers by content for every instruction (like 4 per clock cycle in the front-end) would be very power-expensive.  If software wants caching, it needs to do it in architectural state (registers or memory).

Comment: Then it still works as distributing available physical registers to independent code paths, even on newest archs? (Renaming logical registers to physical ones, just that, no looking at code path duplication?)

Comment: Yes, of course, that *is* what it's for.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo_algorithm hides WAR and WAW hazards, letting the CPU find instruction-level parallelism when a `mov` or whatever overwrites a register without a dependency on the old value.

Comment: For operations with 256bit registers, is it always better to use non-destructive simd commands to help cpu rename them?

Comment: No.  Every register-write needs a physical reg (or pair of them for YMM vectors on Bulldozer-family or Zen1).  Doesn't matter whether it's over-writing one of the inputs, another recently written register, or one that hasn't been written for a long time.